# WIN API GetFileSizeEx() function, was not declared in this scope

Tags: winapi

In my c++ class, I want use WIN API GetFileSizeEx()  function. When I compile my code, the compilator said:

> "error: 'GetFileSizeEx' was not declared in this scope".

However, others functions like CreateFile() or WriteFile() work perfectly.

In my class header, I declare this :

```
#if defined(WINVER) && WINVER==0x0602 /* windows 8 */
#define WINVER 0x0602
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0602
#elif defined(WINVER) && WINVER==0x0601 /* windows 7 */
#define WINVER 0x0601
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601
#elif defined(WINVER) && WINVER==0x0600 /* windows vista and server 2008 */
#define WINVER 0x0600
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600
#elif defined(WINVER) && WINVER==0x0502 /* server 2003 */
#define WINVER 0x0502
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0502
#elif defined(WINVER) && WINVER==0x0501 /* windows xp */
#define WINVER 0x0501
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <winbase.h>
#include <string>
```

In my .cpp class:

```
Test::Test()
{
hFile = CreateFile(TEXT("conf/configure_tool.txt"),
                           GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                           0,
                           NULL,
                           OPEN_EXISTING,
                           0,
                           NULL);

if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    canAcces = false;
}else
{
    if(GetFileSizeEx(hFile,&sized) != 0)
    {
        canAcces = true;
    }
}
}
```

Have you an idea to resolve my problem ?

Comment: That header seems to try to solve a chicken-and-egg problem.  Probably never arriving at the egg.  Get rid of it and just define _WIN32_WINNT to a suitable version.  0x502 is the minimum you should pick if you want to make the mistake to still support XP, 0x600 otherwise.

Comment: Hmm ok, I think I begin to understand. If I use only : #define WINVER 0x0601 #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601 The compiler responsed : "error: "WINVER" redefined" Perhaps I have a problem with this Macro and this is why my previous code don't work?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are defining `WINVER` and `_WIN32_WINNT` in code instead of in your project settings?

Comment: Yeah, because "GetFileSizeEx()" function, don't work and i wanted to try to fix that with WINVER and _WIN32_WINNT.

Comment: Why would defining in code change anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa364957.aspx):

> **Minimum supported client**  Windows XP [desktop apps only]

So you need to ensure that you have defined `WINVER` to be `0x0501` or greater.

If that doesn't solve the problem then the likely cause is that you are using a deficient SDK. Perhaps from an old version of a non-MS compiler. Make sure that you have an up-to-date SDK.

It must be said that the conditional code in the question that attempts to define `_WIN32_WINNT` is a little odd. Why don't you define `_WIN32_WINNT` at the same time as you define `WINVER`?

Comment: Oki, thx for your help. I try to use simple macro for testing : 
#define WINVER 0x0601
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601

But the compiler responded : "error: "WINVER" redefined"

An idea ?

Comment: Well, find out where you defined `WINVER`, and see what value it has. Also, do you have any idea where your SDK came from? Do you know which compiler you use?

Comment: Of course, I use MinGW tdm-gcc 4.8.1 compiler.
For the SDK, I use MinGW win32 "windows.h"

And I define the WINVER after the windows header include.

Comment: So I guess the problem is here then: *If that doesn't solve the problem then the likely cause is that you are using a deficient SDK. Perhaps from an old version of a non-MS compiler. Make sure that you have an up-to-date SDK.*

Comment: I have tried with MinGW tdm-gcc 4.9.2 and same problem. 
Maybe I will use an another solution than 'GetFileSizeEx' function.
Thanks for you assistance.

Comment: I think I answered the question that you asked